# SuiteScript 2.x assigning commission selections on transaction line items

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, clientscript

I am developing a ClientScript for Sales Orders and Quotes. I added a dropdown select transaction line field to select a commission value based on the profit margin of the line item.

For each line item, get the **amount** and **costestimate** and calculate **gross profit**. If the gross profit is within a certain range, set this value on the commission select.

Below is the code I wrote up:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/currentRecord'], (currentRecord)=>{
    
    const CommLoad = (context)=>{
           var currRecord = context.currentRecord,
               lines = currRecord.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });
         
         for(let i=0; i<lines; i++){
             
            const lineNum = currRecord.selectLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i });
             
            var lAmnt = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'amount'});
            var lCost = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'costestimate'});
            var GP = Math.trunc(((lAmnt-lCost)/lAmnt)*100); GP = GP.toFixed(2);
            
            //console.log('line: '+i,'Amount: '+lAmnt,'Cost: '+lCost,'Gross Profit: '+GP);
            
            if (GP < 10.00) { 
                     currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 1
                      });
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 10.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 2
                      });
                     }
                     
                if (GP >= 15.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 3
                      });
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 20.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 4
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 25.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 5
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 30.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 6
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 35.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 7
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 40.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 8
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 45.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 9
                      });
                     }
                     
                 else { 
                  return true;
                }
            
         } //end for

         
    }
    

    
    const CommValidate = (context) =>{
          var currRecord = context.currentRecord,
              lines = currRecord.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' }),
              lineNum = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'line' }),
              lAmnt = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: lineNum, fieldId: 'amount'}),
              lCost = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: lineNum, fieldId: 'costestimate'}),
             GP = Math.trunc(((lAmnt-lCost)/lAmnt)*100); GP = GP.toFixed(2);
            
            //console.log('line: '+lineNum,'Amount: '+lAmnt,'Cost: '+lCost,'Gross Profit: '+GP);
            

            if (GP < 10.00) { 
                     currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 1
                      });
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 10.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 2
                      });
                     }
                     
                if (GP >= 15.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 3
                      });
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 20.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 4
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 25.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 5
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 30.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 6
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 35.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 7
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 40.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 8
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 45.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 9
                      });
                      
                     }
                     
                     
            
    }
    
        const CommFChange = (context) =>{

                     
        }
     
        
    return {
        pageInit: CommLoad, 
        validateLine: CommValidate,
        fieldChanged: CommFChange
    };
    
});
```

The script works perfectly on pageInit, when the line items load up, any without a commission value, will be assigned one.

I am now running into an issue on **validateLine**, I can update the rate or even add a new item and the variables will calculate and assign a commission value, but I am unable to leave the line item, I can keep pressing "add" or "ok" and it will not take me anywhere.

I did try to add a ***commitLine*** to the statements or even outside the statement, and I got this error: *RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded*

Comment: You say "Currently, the script works when..." - do you mean it's working as expected in some scenarios? Can you clarify when the script is working as expected and when it's not?  As a general comment, you're comparing strings instead of numbers, which for this scenario is not best practice.  As an example of why, consider that a lexicographical comparison of strings would give `"5.00%" > "45.00%" = true`

Comment: `Record.commitLine()` is already a function available in the record API.  Do you mean how to attach a function to the event that fires when you add a line?  That would be the `validateLine()` even function.  Follow the same pattern as you did to create the `pageInit` function and reference it in the `return` block.  The `context` passed to `validateLine` will be slightly different, of course, as will the steps you'll want to logically take in the function.

Comment: You don't need a separate script file.  You can include functions for as many of the supported client script entry points as you desire in the one file.  You just need to make sure your return block points each entry point to the function you want it to run.  `return { entryPoint: entryPointFunction }` EG: `return { pageInit: pageInitFunction, validateLine: validateLineFunction, fieldChanged: fieldChangedFunction }`.  The first string of each pair (the "key") needs to be a supported NetSuite entry point, the second (the "value") needs to correspond to a named function in the script file.

Comment: @Krypton, thanks! the validateLine function works great. I can adjust the rate and the value with change, but I cannot get out of the line item. I can keep clicking "ok" and it wont let me go anywhere else. This also goes for when adding new items, we can add it, the commission will popluate, but you can't leave. 

I guess this is where I need to commit, I tried the function but I got the error: RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like at the end of my validateline function, I needed to add a return true.

After I added that, I was able to bounce off onto items and move around. Works like a charm. Thanks again Krypton!

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/currentRecord','N/record'], (currentRecord,record)=>{
    
    const CommLoad = (context)=>{
           var currRecord = context.currentRecord,
               lines = currRecord.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });
         
         for(let i=0; i<lines; i++){
             
            const lineNum = currRecord.selectLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i });
             
            var lAmnt = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'amount'});
            var lCost = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'costestimate'});
            var GP = Math.trunc(((lAmnt-lCost)/lAmnt)*100); GP = GP.toFixed(2);
            
            //console.log('line: '+i,'Amount: '+lAmnt,'Cost: '+lCost,'Gross Profit: '+GP);
            
            if (GP < 10.00) { 
                     currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 1
                      });
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 10.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 2
                      });
                     }
                     
                if (GP >= 15.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 3
                      });
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 20.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 4
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 25.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 5
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 30.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 6
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 35.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 7
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 40.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 8
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 45.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: i,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 9
                      });
                     }
                     
            
         } //end for

         
    }
    

    
    const CommValidate = (context) =>{
          var currRecord = context.currentRecord,
              lineNum = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'line' }),
              lAmnt = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: lineNum, fieldId: 'amount'}),
              lCost = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: lineNum, fieldId: 'costestimate'}),
             GP = Math.trunc(((lAmnt-lCost)/lAmnt)*100); GP = GP.toFixed(2);
            
            //console.log('line: '+lineNum,'Amount: '+lAmnt,'Cost: '+lCost,'Gross Profit: '+GP);
            

            if (GP < 10.00) { 
                     currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 1
                      });
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 10.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 2
                      });
                     }
                     
                if (GP >= 15.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 3
                      });
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 20.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 4
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 25.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 5
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 30.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 6
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 35.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 7
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 40.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 8
                      });
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 45.00) { 
                      currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                          sublistId: 'item',
                          line: lineNum,
                          fieldId: 'custcol3',
                          value: 9
                      });
                      
                     }
                     
                     return true;
        
    }
    
    const CommFChange = (context) =>{ 
    
    }
        
    return {
        pageInit: CommLoad, 
        validateLine: CommValidate,
        fieldChanged: CommFChange
    };
    
});
```