# SuiteScript 2.X How to edit a sales order after a special order PO has been placed

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

The functionality of my [commission value script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77083233/suitescript-2-x-assigning-commission-selections-on-transaction-line-items) was been excellent. While the script will work when editing/creating a sales order and quote, I found a unique scenario in which I must apply the same script.

When a Special Order PO is placed, we can edit the cost estimate *(identified as amount/rate)*. After we submit the PO, it takes us back to the Sales Order. After placing a Special Order PO and if you happen to edit the cost estimate, it will reflect back onto the Sales Order and will affect the Profit Margin.

This is what I am wanting to accomplish:

- *After Special Order PO is placed:*
- Load Sales order (createdfrom)
- Integrate [commission assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77083233/suitescript-2-x-assigning-commission-selections-on-transaction-line-items) script
- save sales order
- *User lands on Sales Order page with newly reassigned commission values*

Below is the code I am trying to get working, the deployment is set to Purchase Orders.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/record', 'N/currentRecord','N/log'], (record,currentRecord,log)=>{
    
    const UpdateSO = (context)=>{
        if(context.type == context.UserEventType.DELETE) {
            return true;
        }
    //begin UpdateSO
            const newPO = context.newRecord,
                  salesOrderId = newPO.getValue({ fieldId: 'createdfrom' });
                  
           if(!salesOrderId) { return true; }
           
            const salesOrderRecord = record.load({ type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, id: salesOrderId,isDynamic: true}),
                  lineItemCount = salesOrderRecord.getLineCount("item");
                  
                  //log.debug('salesOrderRecord',salesOrderRecord);
                  //log.debug('Count',lineItemCount);
                  
            for(let i=0; i<lineItemCount; i++){
             
            const lineNum = salesOrderRecord.selectLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i });
            //log.debug('lineNum',lineNum);
            
            var lAmnt = salesOrderRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'amount'});
            var lCost = salesOrderRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'costestimate'});
            var GP = Math.trunc(((lAmnt-lCost)/lAmnt)*100).toFixed(2);
            
             var ioutput = "item# "+i+", amount: "+lAmnt+", cost: "+lCost+", GP: "+GP;
             log.debug('line value',ioutput);
            
            if (GP <= 9.99) { 
                     salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 1 });
                     log.debug('commission value '+i,1);
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 10.00 && GP < 15.00) { 
                      salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 2 });
                      log.debug('commission value '+i,2);
                     }
                     
                   if (GP >= 15.00 && GP < 20.00) { 
                      salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 3 });
                      log.debug('commission value '+i,3);
                     }
                     
                    if (GP >= 20.00 && GP < 25.00) { 
                      salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 4 });
                      log.debug('commission value '+i,4);
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 25.00 && GP < 30.00) { 
                      salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 5 });
                      log.debug('commission value '+i,5);
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 30.00 && GP < 35.00) { 
                      salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 6 });
                      log.debug('commission value '+i,6);
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 35.00 && GP < 40.00) { 
                      salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 7 });
                      log.debug('commission value '+i,7);
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 40.00 && GP < 45.00) { 
                      salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 8 });
                      log.debug('commission value '+i,8);
                     }
                     
                     if (GP >= 45.00) { 
                      salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 9 });
                      log.debug('commission value '+i,9);
                     }
                     
            
         } //end for
         
        salesOrderRecord.save({ type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, id: salesOrderId, ignoreMandatoryFields: true});
        log.debug('save complete','order saved');
                  
   //end UpdateSO        
    }
    

    return {
        afterSubmit: UpdateSO
    };
    
});
```

I can create the PO, the Sales Order will load with it's line items and set the new values; but it does not show the changes when you land back onto the sales order after submitting your PO.

Do I have the record.save function correct? I don't get an error for this.

```
 salesOrderRecord.save({ type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, id: salesOrderId, ignoreMandatoryFields: true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again for all your help. I was able to figure this out and get the commission values to update.

What I needed to do was after assigning the values, I had to commit the subrecord and then save. Upon testing, it was a success!

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/record', 'N/currentRecord','N/log'], (record,currentRecord,log)=>{

const UpdateSO = (context)=>{
    if(context.type == context.UserEventType.DELETE) {
        return true;
    }
//begin UpdateSO
        const newPO = context.newRecord,
              salesOrderId = newPO.getValue({ fieldId: 'createdfrom' });
              
       if(!salesOrderId) { return true; }
       
        const salesOrderRecord = record.load({ type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, id: salesOrderId,isDynamic: true}),
              lineItemCount = salesOrderRecord.getLineCount("item");
              
              //log.debug('salesOrderRecord',salesOrderRecord);
              //log.debug('Count',lineItemCount);
              
        for(let i=0; i<lineItemCount; i++){
         
        const lineNum = salesOrderRecord.selectLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i });
        //log.debug('lineNum',lineNum);
        
        var lAmnt = salesOrderRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'amount'});
        var lCost = salesOrderRecord.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'costestimate'});
        var GP = Math.trunc(((lAmnt-lCost)/lAmnt)*100).toFixed(2);
        
         var ioutput = "item# "+i+", amount: "+lAmnt+", cost: "+lCost+", GP: "+GP;
         log.debug('line value',ioutput);
        
        if (GP < 10.00) { 
                 salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 1 });
                 salesOrderRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 1 });
                 log.debug('commission value '+i,1);
                 }
                 
                if (GP >= 10.00 && GP < 15.00) { 
                  salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 2 });
                  salesOrderRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 2 });
                  log.debug('commission value '+i,2);
                 }
                 
               if (GP >= 15.00 && GP < 20.00) { 
                  salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 3 });
                  salesOrderRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 3 });
                  log.debug('commission value '+i,3);
                 }
                 
                if (GP >= 20.00 && GP < 25.00) { 
                  salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 4 });
                  salesOrderRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 4 });
                  log.debug('commission value '+i,4);
                 }
                 
                 if (GP >= 25.00 && GP < 30.00) { 
                  salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 5 });
                  salesOrderRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 5 });
                  log.debug('commission value '+i,5);
                 }
                 
                 if (GP >= 30.00 && GP < 35.00) { 
                  salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 6 });
                  salesOrderRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 6 });
                  log.debug('commission value '+i,6);
                 }
                 
                 if (GP >= 35.00 && GP < 40.00) { 
                  salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 7 });
                  salesOrderRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 7 });
                  log.debug('commission value '+i,7);
                 }
                 
                 if (GP >= 40.00 && GP < 45.00) { 
                  salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 8 });
                  salesOrderRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 8 });
                  log.debug('commission value '+i,8);
                 }
                 
                 if (GP >= 45.00) { 
                  salesOrderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 9 });
                  salesOrderRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'custcol3', value: 9 });
                  log.debug('commission value '+i,9);
                 }
                 
        
     } //end for
     
    const saveSalesOrder = salesOrderRecord.save({ type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, id: salesOrderId, ignoreMandatoryFields: true});
    log.debug('save complete','order saved');
              
   //end UpdateSO        
    }


return {
    afterSubmit: UpdateSO
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `salesOrderId` instead the `salesOrderRecord`. That's why you are getting  `TypeError: salesOrderId.getLineCount is not a function`.

Please fix it and let me know if it works with you.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem. But definitely I can help you out. Please reach me out to nadeemkhoury@gmail.com and will setup some time to go through it together. This is free assistance I'm not expecting anything from it.

Comment: Hello Nadeem, Thanks! I'm nearly complete actually. I can create the PO, get the SO, set the new values, but the order does not save it seems. I go back to the SO and the old values are still there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your script. The main ones are that:

- you are trying to get the line count from the sales order id instead of the sales order record.
- you are indexing your items starting at 1 (SS1.0) vs 0 (SS2.x)

Try something like this:

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
**/
define(['N/record'], (record)=>{
    const UpdateSO = (context)=>{
        if(ctx.type == ctx.UserEventType.CREATE || ctx.type == ctx.UserEventType.SPECIALORDER || ctx.type == ctx.UserEventType.DROPSHIP){

            const newPO = context.newRecord, 
            const salesOrderId = newPO.getValue({ fieldId: 'createdfrom' });
            if(!salesOrderId) return;

            const salesOrderRecord = record.load({ type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,  id: salesOrderId });

            const lineItemCount = salesOrderRecord.getLineCount("item");
            // console.log will error or be swallowed in a user event script console.log('salesOrderId ='+salesOrderId,'salesOrderRecord = '+salesOrderRecord,'lineItemCount = '+lineItemCount);
            for (let i = 0; i < lineItemCount; i++) { //SS2 item index is 0 to n-1
                const lineItemInternalId = salesOrderRecord.getLineItemValue("item", "item", i);
                log.debug({ // use log instead of console for server scripts. 
                    title:`Line Item ${i}: ${lineItemInternalId}`,
                    details:null
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        afterSubmit: UpdateSO
    };
});
```