# Ignoring popup messages on Sales Order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I went live with my [commission script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77083233/suitescript-2-x-assigning-commission-selections-on-transaction-line-items), and I began encountering some more issues. These issues only occur when an order has been billed, fulfilled or contains an 'end of group' item.

We get the following messages when an order is either billed, fulfilled or both.

- *Items on this line have been drop shipped or special ordered. Are you sure you want to modify this item*
- *Items on this line have been billed. Are you sure you want to modify this item*

I've been diving into multiple NS/Oracle development articles and I couldn't find anything that I could add to ignore these messages.

**Scenario:**
If you have a sales order that consists of 5 line items and has been billed and fulfilled, the script activates on PageInit, You would immediately be given the popup messages and will have to close it out about 10 times before you can begin to edit the order.

Is there a way for my to write into the script to ignore the messages?

```
             currRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                  sublistId: 'item',
                  line: i,
                  fieldId: 'custcol3',
                  value: 1,
                  **ignoreMessage: true**
              });
```

I also have an issue with **End of Group** lines.

- *You cannot edit the end of group line. You must delete the group (end of line group item)*

These particular items should not be considered, I did try to create a var to get the line item name.

```
var name = currRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', line: i, fieldId: 'name'});
```

The return value gives me the line item internal ID, **end of group** has a value of 0.

I did try to do a currRecord.cancelLine() method, but I could not find the sublistid for groupitems. Would it be *planningitems*? It didn't seem to work for me.